# Custom (Jackson) BigDecimal Deserialization - "override behaviour"

Tags: kotlin, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization, bigdecimal

I am using `Jackson` for deserialaizing `JSON`. We are also using `BigDecimal` type to deserialize an incoming `String` into and this value can contain comma's, e.g. ten thousand can be submitted as "10,000". To be able to deserilaize this value into `BigDeciaml`, I have created a simple custom class:

```
class BigDecimalCommaDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<BigDecimal>() {
    override fun deserialize(parser: JsonParser, context: DeserializationContext): BigDecimal? {
        return if (parser.text != null && parser.text.isNotEmpty())
            BigDecimal(parser.text.replace(",", ""))
        else null
    }
}
```

and wired up as follows:

```
    @JsonDeserialize(using = BigDecimalCommaDeserializer::class)
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    var unitCount: BigDecimal? = null,
```

I notice though, there is also a `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.BigDecimalDeserializer`. Will this still be called, or should i think about delegating a call to it from my `BigDecimalCommaDeserializer`?

Answer (score 0):

Custom deserialiser, `BigDecimalCommaDeserializer`, will be used in that case. Common one, `BigDecimalDeserializer`, will be used by default in all other places where custom deserialiser is not specified.